What is the Name of this Integration Trick?
There is this trick I've learned for solving integrals but I'm unsure if this technique has a certain name. I'll give two examples below.
$$\int\frac{x}{x+1}dx$$
$$\int\frac{x+1-1}{x+1}dx = \int\left(1-\frac{1}{x+1}\right ) dx$$
And another:
$$\int\frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}dx $$
$$\int\frac{e^x+1-2}{e^x+1}dx = \int\left( 1-\frac{2}{e^x+1}\right ) dx$$
It's very useful, but I have trouble spotting it in situations where it can be used. I'm looking for a name to try and find similar problems to help with my recognition.

the first example is basically long division

I'm not sure how the second one helps.

I call this 'trick' by long division or experience or mathematical maturity.

@StefanLafon you can multiply and divide by $e^{-x}$ but I don't know if this is OP's idea

Makes sense, thanks @SineoftheTime.

Some people call it the camel principle.

It can also be useful in expanding to partial fractions. For example,$$\frac1{x(1-x)}=\frac{(1-x)+x}{x(1-x)}=\frac1x+\frac1{1-x}$$
